# What is the Haldane phase?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, definition, spin-models, phase-diagram

I'm trying to look up what is the [Haldane phase](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=&as_epq=haldane+phase), but the only thing I find is examples of physical systems that "realize" the Haldane phase, such as the AKLT model, but no clear definition of what this Haldane phase is. Can anybody provide a definition?

Comment: See "Colloquium: Zoo of quantum-topological phases of matter" by Wen X. G. where he discusses 'Haldane phases' quite extensive on a understandable level. There, he defines the Haldane phase as the gapped ground state of an integer spin chain.